# DOM memory leak with angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, dom

My company is building a large scale application and we have created a very large 5000+ line component. That said, we've came across a place in the application that has a memory leak. We feel that this is do to us adding thousands of controls into the DOM. 
We have narrowed it down to where we're pushing objects into an array, and when the garbage collector cleans that up we don't thing that it is removing all of the nodes from the DOM. With all of that said we have hit a brick wall in trying to clean this up so any help would be appreciated. I have also created a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZpFTXljXKBWrHVRLvpKF?p=preview) similar to what we're doing and have reproduced the memory leak on a much smaller scale then our application. Can you please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

The code to look at is:

**.html**

```
<div>
<div class="col-sm-1 left-column">
  <div> </div>
  <div *ngFor="let line of lines">{{line.LineName}}</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-11">
  <div *ngFor="let column of columns" class="col-sm-1">
    <span class=column-header>{{column?.Title}}</span>
    <div *ngFor="let line of column?.LineModels"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(private exampleService:ExampleService){
  }

  private lines:LineModel[]=[];
  private columns:ColumnModel[]=[];

  ngOnInit(){
    this.lines = this.exampleService.GetLines();
    this.columns = this.exampleService.GetColumns();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    //I have tried to lines.removeAt(line.LineIndex) doesnt remove from DOM.
  }

}
```

**Chrome Snap Shot**
[image: Chrome Snap shot]

**Going out a second time**
[image]

Comment: Do you have things like a manually added array of event handlers that don't get removed? So every time you addEventListener, you pass function ref. like this.elements.forEach(el => addEventListener('click',this.clickhandler)), so you can do mirror in removeEventListener onDestroy.. and have clickhander =( () => {this. //enable this}).bind(this);

Comment: Is there any way you can refactor the code? The Angular docs suggest keeping files to a maximum of 400 lines. I don't know, seems more manageable.

Comment: Is your service registered to only use the root context (forRoot())? In other words is your problem component within a lazy loaded module? If so you may be spawning multiple instances of the same service.

Comment: I ran chrome heap snapshot on your plunker vs an empty plunker and in both plunkers they had the same number of detached nodes which means there are no detached nodes in your plunker due to your code. I also used the allocation timeline and clicked back and forth between "Read Me" and "Example" and it mostly cleared all of the memory.  Can you add some screenshots of graphs that show the memory leak happening?

Comment: I have went through and removed all of the event handlers and the html there is still a memory leak

Comment: @seescode I can send a screen shot if you can tell me your email or a place to send it to

Comment: It's possible to put screen shots within your stack overflow question.  Just save it as an image and upload as an image.

Comment: I have added the graph

Comment: can you please show your service code?

Comment: the service is about 15 layers, which part are you wanting to see?

Comment: ok, that sounds too big to show here, never mind. so, looking at your plunker example, your service is most likely the problem and the reason is that you have properties defined on your services. It's a known bug in angular: services that have anything else (properties/fields) than methods don't get GCed. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13725 and services error reproduced: https://github.com/rmullins9/angular2-service-destruction/blob/master/src/app/instructions/instructions.component.html that is the first thing i'd try to check if i were you.

Comment: thank you. We will try to do this, when we figure it out I will post anwser on here.

Comment: yes please do as this kind of thing/experience is very important for all of us.

Comment: @JT1979 did you ever figure this out?